# Webhook not called when someone comment on facebook page's post

Tags: facebook, post, comments

I am trying to fetch my fb page post's comment on my website but webhook is not getting called when comments arrive,

I have tested with test feed from developers account and i am getting successfully response on my webhook, 
but when i try with live page and comment on my page then webhook is not getting call and also i want user information who comment.

Please guide with configuration settings

Comment: Is your app live or in dev mode? Do you have all relevant stuff reviewed already, if in live mode? If not in live mode, what user accounts are you testing with - do they have a role in the app?

Comment: @CBroe i am testing in dev mode and other apps reviewed successfully but not getting approval for page public content access.